# Measuring distance using GSM antennas

Tags: distance, gsm

Scenario:

Just imagine a big hall, let's say 20 meters x 30 meters. In this hall there are people walking. Imagine that each person has a mobile phone. We would like to determine the position of each mobile with an accuracy of 1 meter.

Question:

The question I've been asked is if this is possible by using local GSM antennas. I mean, if it is possible to allocate antennas inside the hall so that each phone is registered at the cells. Each cell should track every X amount of seconds the distance from the cell to the phone and send this info to a local server.

Has anybody experience on this? 
Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It will probably not work well in practice - the signal paths will be complex (reflections from walls/floor/ceiling, absorption by human bodies, etc) and there will also be interference issues (desens in receiver front ends etc).

Comment: hey Luixv, I want to use the same thing in my android app, if you have done this, please share tks